# Как добавить класс только одному элементу при скролле?

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт

```
function come(elem) {
var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height(),
    elemTop = $(elem).offset().top,
    elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

     return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

function mainAnim() {
   if (come('.js-animation')) {
      $('.js-animation').addClass('animation');
   }
}

$('.js-animation').each(function () {
    $(document).on('scroll', function () {
        mainAnim();
});

mainAnim();

});
```

Есть несколько блоков с классом .js-animation, при загрузке и скролле всем этим классам добавляется .animation.
Так вот как сделать так что бы animation добавился до текущего js-animation.

Как правильно перебрать все js-animation через each и добавить класс только там, куда доскролили

Comment: Что значит *что бы animation добавился до текущего js-animation*?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ну есть 4 блока .js-animation и сейчас когда доскролил до первого .js-animation то класс animation добавляется все остальным блокам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
$(function () {
    function come(elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
            docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height(),
            elemTop = elem.offset().top,
            elemBottom = elemTop + elem.height();

        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }

    function mainAnim() {
        $('.js-animation').each(function(){
            var elem = $(this);
            if (come(elem)) {
                elem.addClass('animation');
            }
        })
    }

    $(document).on('scroll', function () {
        mainAnim();
    });
    mainAnim();
});
```

Данный код нужно оптимизировать в плане перформанса, но в целом работать должен.